# Задача на Go "быстрый поиск"

Tags: golang

Не понимаю, как решать, условие ниже

На первой строке передается количество людей в списке - натуральное число. Затем на следующих строках идет список людей. А после списка - перечень префиксов всех тех, кого надо найти. Перечень префиксов может быть произвольной длины. Пустая строка вместо префикса значит что префиксы закончились.

Для каждого префикса необходимо вывести первую фамилию с таким префиксом, или фразу Не найдено.

Ввод

```
3
Иванов Иван
Петренко Тарас
Петров Дмитрий
Ив
Петр
Петра
```

Вывод

```
Иванов Иван
Петренко Тарас
Не найдено
```

мой код:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Scan(&n)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    people := make([]string, n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        scanner.Scan()
        people[i] = scanner.Text()
    }

    sort.Strings(people)

    prefixes := make([]string, 0)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        scanner.Scan()
        prefixes = append(prefixes, scanner.Text())
    }

    for _, prefix := range prefixes {

        index := sort.Search(len(people), func(j int) bool {
            return strings.HasPrefix(people[j], prefix)
        })

        if index < len(people) {
            fmt.Println(people[index])
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Не найдено")
        }
    }
}
```

выводит
Не найдено
Петренко Тарас
Не найдено

вместо
Иванов Иван
Петренко Тарас
Не найдено

Comment: Совсем-совсем не понимаете, даже сравнить строки не можете? Тогда пока о trie рано говорить

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Почему вы читаете N префиксов, а не до пустой строки?

Comment: `sort.Search` не будет работать с функцией `strings.HasPrefix`. У них разное представление о порядке строк. Читайте про trie или дерево префиксов.